# What does "briefing provisions" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> Meeting will be conducted by the manager, specific to the scheduled
>   operations and in compliance with the approved manual, briefing
>   provisions.

Does it mean "... with the approved manual, which is briefing provisions", "... with the briefing provisions of the approved manual", or "... with the approved manual and briefing provisions"?

Usually when a comma is used without prepositions or anything, it means "i.e.", but I am not sure if it means "i.e." in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This sounds like an error to me.** Eliminating the comma would be one way to correct the statement, but depending on what is meant, the correct statement could be different.